# Identify this Intel Core 2 Quad engineering sample

Tags: cpu

Which is this Intel Confidential cpu? It has 2333MHz Core + 12MB Cache

[image: intel confidential core 2 quad]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the processor itself?

Comment: yes, i will upload now...

Comment: What do you mean?  Why do you call it 'Confidential'?

Comment: @JuliePelletier: Intel Engineering Samples are always marked "Intel Confidential" on the IHS.

Comment: A core 2 quad is far from being new technology.  I bought one almost identical to that about 7 years ago.

Comment: they deleted it from site, sold it already, i wanted one, i can't upload image... it can be something like this http://ark.intel.com/products/33080/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5410-12M-Cache-2_33-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB they said it was better than 9550

Comment: @JuliePelletier old but gold ! they are still very good !

Comment: True, I agree it's a nice CPU.

Comment: We cannot based on the information supplied by you identify the hardware you have.  You have been asked for the information, required to identify this hardware, until thats been supplied this question cannot be answered.

Comment: @GeorgeG. where did you get it from if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Burgi I wanted to buy it from some guy, price was 25$- used very good. but yesterday he sold it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ES" in the Specification means it's an "[Engineering Sample](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005719.html)", and so was never released to the public, so it doesn't have an official model number, nor will it be included in Intel's ARK site.

A [Q9550](http://ark.intel.com/products/33924/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9550-12M-Cache-2_83-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) is a 12MB cached chip with 2.83GHz, it's a better/newer chip than this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's [45nm *Yorkfield*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors#Yorkfield_.2845_nm.29) but your chip seems to be a prerelease version that is slower-clocked than any production part in this line (MCM with 2x6MB cache). (The [Q9450](http://ark.intel.com/products/33923/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9450-12M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) was clocked at 2.66 GHz but your processor is clocked at 2.33 GHz.)

As this is an [engineering sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_sample), it has no official model number. It's basically a preproduction chip meant for testing purposes under an NDA, and was never meant for public release (hence Intel Confidential). [More information on engineering samples from Intel.](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005719.html)